# jsontohtml data not transforming

Tags: json

I have JSON data which looks like this:

> [{"tabname":"orders","datagroups":[{"dataname":"ordersToday","datavalue":87}, 
>   {"dataname":"orders30Days","datavalue":305}]},{"tabname":"second","datagroups": 
>   [{"dataname":"Test","datavalue":17}]}]

My transform file looks like this:

> var transformTabs = 
>       {"tag":"div","id":"${tabname}","class":"tabContent","children":[ 
>       { "tag":"div", "class":"datagroup","children":[ 
>       {"tag":"div","id":"${dataname}","class":"dataContent","children":[ 
>       { "tag":"div", "class":"data","children":[ 
>       {"tag":"p","html":"${dataname}-${datavalue}"} 
>       ]}
>       ]}
>       ]}
>       ]}

For some reason dataname and datavalue are not being transformed – nothing is appearing in where these values should appear. I used your builder to create the transform. Can you please tell me what I have missed.

Here’s my raw data before JSON encoding:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tabname] => orders
            [datagroups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [dataname] => ordersToday
                            [datavalue] => 17
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [dataname] => orders30Days
                            [datavalue] => 43
                        )
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tabname] => second
            [datagroups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [dataname] => Test
                            [datavalue] => 17
                        )
                )
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly when using [json2html](http://json2html.com) to transform from json to html you need to keep in mind that the transform is only looking at the top level objects in the data array and wont be parsing the sub arrays.

```
[{"tabname":"orders","datagroups":[]},{"tabname":"second","datagroups":[]}]
```

so json2html will have no idea that ${dataname} and ${datavalue} are stored in datagroups.

Perhaps try and re-structuring you json output to this

```
[{"tabname":"orders","dataname":"test1","datavalue":5},{"tabname":"second","dataname":"test2","datavalue":6}]
```

OR you can try to use a transform that parses the sub datagroups array like this

```
var transforms = {
'tab':{"tag":"div","id":"${tabname}","class":"tabContent","children":function() {
    return(json2html.transform(this.datagroups,transforms.group));
}},
'group':{ "tag":"div", "class":"datagroup","children":[
                {"tag":"div","id":"${dataname}","class":"dataContent","children":[
                    { "tag":"div", "class":"data","children":[
                            {"tag":"p","html":"${.dataname}-${datavalue}"}
                    ]}
                ]}
        ]}
```

};

[JS Fiddle for working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2VwKb/)